# Is it possible to use statistics to detect a rising temperature scenario?

Tags: time-series, change-point, quality-control

It is required to monitor temperature data from a manufacturing environment. The particular use case is to detect if the temperature is rising beyond normal values to enable timely corrective action. The temperature data is being collected by an IoT sensor.

Sample data below. It's time series data so time is plotted on the X axis.
[image]
Currently static thresholds are being used for alerting purposes but it would be preferable to use a dynamic method. I have tried simple linear regression but this wasn't accurate as there is no predictor data available, only sample time and temperature readings.
Is it possible to apply a statistical method for this use case?

Comment: look into control charts, search this site.

Comment: Have been investigating control charts for variables and have some further questions on this. My use case is for real time data which is being sampled every 5 minutes. Can control charts be used in this scenario?  Also I have found that if the moving range standard deviation is used the control bands seem to too narrow resulting in a lot of false alerts. However if I use the sample standard deviation the control bands are wider and I get better results. Why is this the case?